Как append() влияет на len и cap слайса (slice) в Go?
Как функция append() влияет на длину (len) и вместимость (cap) слайса (slice) в гошке. Изменения cap слайса (slice) происходят нелинейно по отношению к количеству добавленных элементов. Почему изменяется cap среза после каждого вызова append?
Также возникает вопрос, можно ли этим как-нибудь управлять?
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // Создаем срез с начальной длиной 0 и вместимостью 3
    slice := make([]int, 0, 3)
    fmt.Printf("Initial len: %d, cap: %d\n", len(slice), cap(slice)) // len: 0, cap: 3
    
    // Добавляем первый элемент в срез
    slice = append(slice, 1)
    fmt.Printf("After append 1: len: %d, cap: %d\n", len(slice), cap(slice)) // len: 1, cap: 3
    
    // Добавляем второй элемент в срез
    slice = append(slice, 2)
    fmt.Printf("After append 2: len: %d, cap: %d\n", len(slice), cap(slice)) // len: 2, cap: 3
    
    // Добавляем третий элемент в срез
    slice = append(slice, 3)
    fmt.Printf("After append 3: len: %d, cap: %d\n", len(slice), cap(slice)) // len: 3, cap: 3
    
    // Добавляем четвертый элемент, что приводит к увеличению вместимости среза
    slice = append(slice, 4)
    // Здесь `cap` может удвоиться до 6, но точное значение может зависеть от реализации
    fmt.Printf("After append 4: len: %d, cap: %d\n", len(slice), cap(slice)) // len: 4, cap: 6
}


Если по простому: пока len>cap - просто пишем в свободные ячейки, как только len<cap - создаем новый массив в два раза больше исходного и копируем туда старый...
Какнибудь управлять - выделять память явно, не отдавая на откуп автоматике...
